# Combining Two PHP Codes for a Theme Options Panel

Tags: php, wordpress

Usually PHP questions are strayed away from on the WP stackexchange site so here's a question I had...

to_count_portfolio calls a number of posts selected in a options panel

```
<?php echo get_option('to_count_portfolio'); ?>
```

I have a custom query setup and where the "3" is I need to have to_count_portfolio instead. Here is my current code:

```
    <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
); 
    ?>
```

I'm going to assume I need to include `$per_page = get_option('to_count_portfolio');` somewhere, but I'm stuck from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `3` with `get_option('to_count_portfolio')`. Done.

You understand the logic behind? If not just ask.